# How to merge data from two different lasers

Tags: ros, hokuyo-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use 1 hokuyo_node to publish to 'scan' and another hokuyo_node to publish to 'scan_1' I tried using the ira_laser_tool package but scan_mulit is not reaction.

```
<node pkg="ira_laser_tools" name="laserscan_multi_merger" type="laserscan_multi_merger" output="screen">
 <param name="destination_frame" value="/base_link"/>
 <param name="cloud_destination_topic" value="/merged_cloud"/>
 <param name="scan_destination_topic" value="/scan_multi_merged"/>
 <param name="laserscan_topics" value ="/scan /scan1" /> 
</node>
```

I use `rosnode info /scan_multi` show:

```
Node [/scan_multi]
Publications: None

Subscriptions: None

Services: None

cannot contact [/scan_multi]: unknown node
```

So,someone can tell me how to solve this problem. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274629/how-to-merge-data-from-two-different-lasers/) by [Maxes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31404/maxes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
I'm confused:

- you have `scan_destionation_topic` set to `/scan_multi_merged`, not `/scan_multi`
- `rosnode info ..` checks *nodes*, **not** topics
- your "[an]other hokuyo_node" publishes to `scan_1`, not `/scan1` according to your description

please check these things and report back.

**Comment by [Maxes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31404/maxes/) on 2017-10-31**:
Hey gvdhoom , I change it you said but I open /scan_multi_merged topic in rviz,  it only shows that scan is not merged. What information do I need to let you know my difficulties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [related question](https://answers.ros.org/question/273572/how-to-use-ira_laser_tools-package-to-merge-laser-datas/#273809) with an answer.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0